# How to fix java.exe finished with non-zero exit value 2

Tags: android

I run my application in android studio. I have repeatitive class in 2 different folder in my project. When run it this i see this error:

```
Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

How can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You can fix the issue using removing some unused libraries and methods from dependencies in build.gradle, OR by adding multidex support.

OR

If you have to keep libraries and methods, then you can enable multi dex support by declaring it in the gradle config.

```
defaultConfig {        
    // Enabling multidex support.
multiDexEnabled true
}
```

Comment: thank you. it solved this problem but after adding "multiDexEnable true" see this error:"could not find class x referenced from method y"

Comment: First Add this dependencie: **com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1**   After then Create one class which extends **Application** Class and Override **attachBaseContext** method.  And add this Line : **MultiDex.install(this);**